# DocuSign Api: how to get the envelope blurb and title without the status

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to retrieve the blurb, title and recipients for an envelope without polling for the status at the same time?  The reason for asking is that it appears from the API documentation that any calls to /account/{accountid}/envelopes appear to be classed as a status update.

Answer (score 1):

To get email blurb and title, you use the *Get Individual Envelope Status* operation:

```
GET /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}
```

To get recipients, you use the *Get Envelope Recipient Status* operation:

```
GET /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients
```

The reference to "status" in these operation names is simply the naming convention that DocuSign decided to use (since the operations are commonly used to determine status of envelope / recipients) -- but the API responses contain lots of additional information beyond just status.

Comment: Thanks Kim - so do those calls not count towards the status polling limit (1 per 15 minutes per unique envelope)?

Comment: They do count towards the polling limits. So don't use those calls to poll for status more than once every 15 minutes per unique envelope id. What are you trying to do? @Wax_Lee

Comment: Our application allows the users to enter blurb, title, recipients etc via our UI but then passes control to DocuSign's UI for signature placement.  However, users are also able to modify these properties via that window at the same time.  In the absence (as far as I can tell) of a function to disable this we wanted to retrieve any changes that the user makes to the envelope in the DocuSign UI.